# Discord.py try to get all user list in discord

Tags: python, discord.py

i try to get all users my discord channel, i send message bot !find but its response
how can iget all members id ?

```
[<Member id=****name='*****' discriminator='6148' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=******name='*******' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=104>>]
```

```
import discord

TOKEN = ""
GUILD = ""
CHANNEL_ID = ""

client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)
    members = client.guilds[0].members
    print(members[:10])
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: you get list with objects and you have to use `for`-loop to work with every object separatelly and get `.id` from object. ie. `print( x.id for x in memebers[:10] )` or `for x in memebers[:10]: print(x.id)`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop through your list of `Member`s and grab each of their ID. For example:

```py
# ... other code
members = client.guilds[0].members

member_ids = []
for member in members:
  member_ids.append(member.id)

print(member_ids)
# ... other code
```

Or, even better, you can use a list comprehension:

```py
# ... other code
members = client.guilds[0].members

member_ids = [member.id for member in members]

print(member_ids)
# ... other code
```